# Local class instance creation expression in a static-context

Tags: java, class, local-class

The [JLS 15.9.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.2) tells us how to determine an enclosing instance:
Let C be the class being instantiated, and let i be the instance being created.

> If C is an inner class, then i may have an immediately enclosing
>   instance (§8.1.3), determined as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> If C is a local class, then:
>
> - If C occurs in a static context, then i has no immediately enclosing
>     instance.
> - **Otherwise, if the class instance creation expression occurs in a**
>     **static context, then a compile-time error occurs.**
> - Otherwise, let O be the immediately enclosing class of C. Let n be an
>     integer such that O is the n'th lexically enclosing type declaration
>     of the class in which the class instance creation expression appears.
>
> The immediately enclosing instance of i is the n'th lexically
>   enclosing instance of this.

I didn't get what the bolded case means. Let me provide the example I wasn't supposed to be compiled:

```
class A{
    int a;
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
        class Foo{
            void bar(){
            }
        }
        Foo f = new Foo(); //Instance creation expression occured in the static context
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/E2mKbg)**

What's wrong with that? Couldn't you provide an actual example describing the second point?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following case is meant:

```
public class A {

   public class B { /* ... */ }

   public static void createB() {
      new B();  // <<=== This should fail
   }
}
```

The marked line should fail, since the inner class B is not static, so it requires en enclosing instance of A. There is no such enclosing instance, since the method `createB()` is static.

**UPDATE**: I mistook the question beeing about inner classes in general, which is what my example shows. In the context of Local Classes I also can't interpret the documentation.

Comment: But the B class is not a local class. I thought the marked line was talking about exactly local classes.

Comment: OK, I give up. I also don't know what that sentence means. I'll have to dig in further.

Comment: The thing is when the declaration of the local class occured in a non-static context, how is it even possible to embed the instance creation expression of the class into a static-context. Is it ever possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should read these two lines :

> - If C occurs in a static context, then i has no immediately enclosing instance.
> - Otherwise, if the class instance creation expression occurs in a static context, then a compile-time error occurs.

Your case is the first case - you defined the class `Foo` in a static context (the `main` method), and therefore the instance `f` has no enclosing instance.

If, however, you'd define the class `Foo` outside the `main` method, and try to create the instance of `Foo` in the `main` method, you'll get an error, unless you change `Foo` to be a static class.

```
class A
{
    int a;
    class Foo
    {
        void bar()
        {
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Foo f = new Foo(); // this should fail
    }
}
```

Comment: But Foo is not a local class. The quote is talking about local classes.

Comment: Moreover there was no anything about _direct inner classes of some another class_ which are defined in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1